# Moment-generating function of a generalised normal random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable that follows the "version 1" generalised normal distribution described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution), with p.d.f.

$$f_X(x;\mu,\alpha,\beta)=k\exp\left\{-\left(\frac{|x-\mu|}{\alpha}\right)^\beta\right\}\enspace,$$

where

$$k=\frac{\beta}{2\alpha\Gamma(1/\beta)}\enspace,$$

and let $Y=e^X$. Is there a closed-form expression for $E[Y]$? If so, what is it? More generally, is there a closed-form expression for the moment-generating function $M_X(t)=E\left[e^{tX}\right]$?

I began with

\begin{align}
E[Y]&= E\left[e^X\right] \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^xf_X(x) dx \\
 &= k\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left\{x-\left(\frac{|x-\mu|}{\alpha}\right)^\beta\right\}dx \enspace,
\end{align}

but I'm not sure how to find a closed-form solution, or if one exists. Presumably the integral diverges when $\beta< 1$, as $f_X$ decays subexponentially in this case.

I also tried to solve it in terms of the p.d.f. $f_Y$ of $Y$, which is:

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{f_X(\ln y)}{y}\enspace.$$

This leads to the expression:

$$E[Y]=\int_{0}^\infty f_X(\ln y) dy \enspace,$$

but again I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: That's correctly known as a Subbotin distribution (after Subbotin 1923), notwithstanding Nadarajah and various other johnny-come latelies attempt to re-label it as something else. The end result is a mess, as reflected in the wiki page write-up.

Comment: This paper discusses properties of a random variable whose logarithm's distribution looks similar to f_X: http://www.hindawi.com/journals/jps/2013/432642/ . In section 3, they only give formulas for the moments in the general case in terms of infinite series, so perhaps there is no closed-form solution...